# How do I save a user's filter criteria?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, laravel

I have a Laravel application using a MySQL database with millions of records across multiple tables which look as follows when simplified:

```
Table: products  
Columns: product_id name price stockist colour brand stock date_added

Table: stockists  
Columns: stockist_id name phone email post_code stock

Table: categories  
Columns: category_id name slug level

Table: category_product  
Columns: category_id product_id
```

Users are able to search for products based on a large number of criteria (approximately 15), encompassing almost all product-related data. A sample search may look like this:

Return the first 50 products which:
- cost more than £5
- cost less than £30
- are branded by 'Apple', 'Samsung', or 'LG'
- belong to the categories 'usb chargers' or 'batteries' but not 'cases' or 'covers' or 'in-car chargers'
- were added less than two weeks ago

I want to be able to store the search parameters against the user that made them in order for them to be able to rerun the search multiple times. From my research the solutions I've come across include views which I don't believe will work as they don't accept parameters and prepared statements which wouldn't work either as they cannot be saved. That leaves stored procedures or saving to a dedicated table with a column for each parameter. I'm leaning towards the latter of the two, although I can see that getting very messy very quickly. Can someone point me towards the best solution to the problem? Thanks.

Comment: Persistent data should reside in persistent storage. A database works for this. To keep it scalable you could take the $_GET parameters, serialize or JSON encode them and store them in a search history table under a single column. If more filter parameters are added the technique will still work without modification. (Make sure you filter/validate the input prior to storage and sanitize on the way out). You could add a name column and then your user could look through their stored queries and pick one.

Comment: @CurtisKelsey I quite like the idea of storing a JSON encoded object. Mapping columns to each parameter singly would likely still require storage of multiple values in a single column since it's possible to use OR conditions or even SELECT * WHERE column IN ('a', 'b', 'c').

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to maintain a list of filter columns, you can use a key-value store pattern.

```
table: user_search_criteria
columns: user_id, key, value

$criterium = new UserSearchCriteria();
$criterium->user_id = $user->id;
$criterium->key     = 'price';
$criterium->value   = '<= 100';
$criterium->save();
```

But I guess you don't have to remember criteria for a very long time, so I'd use Redis for this.

```
Redis::set('criteria.' . $username, $criteria);

$criteria = Redis::get('criteria.' . $username);
```

Comment: Sadly one of the requirements is to persist the data indefinitely, so whilst I am using Redis, it can't be used for this particular feature. The key-value store looks a potentially good solution - I'll do some further reading on it, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You may use `$_SESSION`.

```
$_SESSION['seach_critera'] = json_encode($criterea_array);
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php